# not used characters from ANSI characters set

Tags: ide, markup, ansi

I'am developing a small programming language together with an IDE.

The ANSI character set states the subset of unused characters. Here is the complete list: 0x7F, 0x81, 0x8D, 0x8F, 0x90, 0x9D

I'd like to use some of them for an invisible code markup, so am wondering how they got printed in different environments. Can I assume they are always a whitespace, or some editors will take the honor to replace them with something like '?' or grey rectangle?

Thank you, Dmitry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't assume any specific behavior, as it will depend on the display widget and quite possibly on the font.  Either preprocess the text for display or use an out-of-band markup mechanism (for example, many text field widgets let you attach attributes to runs of text).

Comment: Yes, I do preprocess the text in my IDE, but displaying the same file in different editor can become a problem.

Comment: The usual solution to that is either to "hide" the markup in comments or use a custom file format with export capability.  Random other editors stand a very good chance of corrupting your markup otherwise.  (Never forget that some people, for reasons known only to them, edit text files in Word.)

Comment: Yes, having a companion file describing the markup of the main one seems like the only robust solution.

Comment: That's not robust either:  if the text file is changed enough, you may not be able to reassociate the contexts of the auxiliary file with it.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be talking about [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), which is just one of many "ANSI" code pages Windows can use, and it's probably not used outside of Windows. Don't tie a new product to an obsolete technology. Not supporting Unicode (be it UTF-16le or UTF-8) is unacceptable for a programming language.

While it's rather moot to answer the direct question, the answer is no, you cannot assume they will be treated as whitespace. Some may. Some may replace with a space. Some may replace with another glyph. Some may use special colours. Some may give a warning. Some may not load the file.

By the way, if you are referring to Windows-1252, only 0x81, 0x8D, 0x8F, 0x90, 0x9D aren't assigned.

Comment: Unless the user decides to use some characters outside the ANSI set, the file should be saved as an ANSI one. This is what all IDE editors do unrelative to their Unicode support.

Comment: That plain not true. Editors do not tend to switch to ANSI from UTF-8 or UTF-16le. Not the simple one (e.g. notepad), and definitely not the high end ones either (why would they alter your data for no reason?). Furthermore, you're still saying "ANSI" when you mean "Windows-1252". Like I already said, not all machines use Windows-1252. Not even all Windows machines. My work machines uses bytes the bytes you inquired about.

Comment: Actually ANSI (not ASCII) is just a subset of Unicode, the first [0..127] of it. And, BTW, the Unicode data encoded in UTF-8 will be identical to the ANSI one (this is the main beauty of UTF-8). By ANSI I really mean ANSI - when all the bytes in the file have their highest bit = 0 - which is a very common case.

Comment: @Dmitry Sychov, You have it backwards. ASCII (not ANSI) is the first 128 characters of Unicode. ANSI and UNICODE is what Windows calls the Active Code Page (usually 1252) and UTF-16le (UCS-2le?) respectively.

Comment: @Dmitry Sychov, If you want to change your question from cp1252 (which doesn't define 0x81, 0x8D, 0x8F, 0x90, 0x9D) to ASCII (which doesn't defined 0x80..0xFF), the previously given answers still apply.